# Nestjs validation pipe not working with Graphql

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

I am new to nestJS and I have added a ValidationPipe() to main.ts

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe())
```

Now I am using class-validator decorators inside my DTO's but nothing is working right now.
I am using GraphQl but as I have already configured the pipe globally it must work.

Is there any more configuration that needs to be done and I am missing that?
Please help.

Comment: Honestly, that should be all that's necessary. And specifying the type in the route handler, just as you do with REST. Can you provide a minimum reproduction? Or access to your code? Show what isn't working.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with transform:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_PIPE } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_PIPE,
      useClass: ValidationPipe,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```